# Time-consuming operation

Tags: performance, time, comparison, variable-assignment

if I have two integer variables with allocated memory and value a and b, which is the more time consuming (time of execution by the processor) operation: comparison `(a == b)` or assignment `(a = b)` ? And why?

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on your processor architecture and the resulting binary executable.

Comment: on a X86 and java compiler, what will be the results?

Comment: Most java compilers will not deliver a binary executable.

Comment: @gabi: why don't you try it and submit your own answer? It's really hard to tell what would happen in theory, and even so, it would only be a theoretical answer, which is probably of little use to most.

Answer (score 0):

Because the assignment involves a memory write (assuming that a is not a local value held in a register), chances are that it is slower on contemporary processors.